# VBS logout script to repeatedly prompt the user to enter a password every 15 seconds

Tags: vbscript

I am currently working on a VBS script that prompts the user to enter a password every 60 seconds. The script is intended to log the user out if they enter the wrong password twice within a 60 second interval, or if there is no response.

However, I am having trouble figuring out how to detect if the inputbox has been inactive for more than 60 seconds. Can anyone please help me with this issue? I would greatly appreciate any suggestions or solutions.

Also, is there any way to fix bugs in the code that may cause the script to malfunction?

```
Dim Password, Input, count
Password = "qq"
count = 0
Do
    Do
        Input = InputBox("Please enter your password:", "Password Required", "")
        If Input = Password Then
            Exit Do
        Else
            count = count + 1
            Input = InputBox("Please enter your password:", "Password Required", "")

            If count = 2 Then
                Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
                objShell.Run "shutdown /l", 0, True
            End If
        End If
    Loop
    WScript.Sleep 60000
Loop
```

Comment: Is this meant to be a prank? If not, then I suggest seriously thinking through what you're trying to achieve. As presented, it makes no sense.

Comment: The first thing to understand is that an InputBox (or MsgBox) in VBScript stops all script processing until the dialog is closed. What you're trying to achieve requires some sort of asynchronous processing, so you could make it work as an HTA.

Comment: @LesFerch Thanks so much for bringing that to my attention . Now that you've explained it, I completely understand where you're coming from . The idea behind the script was to prevent me from nodding off at my computer and leaving it open by accident . If the input box goes inactive for more than 15 seconds, the script automatically logs me out for added security . You had a great point about using HTA for asynchronous processing, I'll definitely look into it . I really appreciate the suggestion , thank you for your help!

Comment: Did you try the code I posted in the answer below?

Comment: I just checked the code you posted in the answer below and I must say, it worked amazingly. I am impressed with the level of detail and the clear explanations provided in the code. It was very easy to follow and implement. I appreciate the time and effort you took to provide such a comprehensive answer. Thanks for sharing your knowledge and expertise.

Comment: You're welcome. Glad to have helped and the positive feedback is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically, all you need to do to protect the computer when nodding off is to a) ensure your account has a password, and b) set the computer to automatically turn off the display after a set period (e.g. 15 minutes) and ensure that the option, `On resume, display logon screen` is checked. And, if you're prone to nodding off while watching movies, use a video player that allows you to keep the screensaver enabled. In VLC, for example, you would uncheck the `Disable screensaver` setting.

However, if you're using software that disables the screensaver and doesn't have an option to leave it enabled, then you may need a script like the one below. This is an HTA that displays a countdown for whatever timeout you set in the script and logs you out when the  countdown reaches zero. Whenever you click the `Reset Countdown` button (or press F5), it resets the countdown back to the timeout value.

This should suffice as a "doze guard". There's no point in prompting for a password unless you want to ensure no one else can mess with the countdown (including not being able to just kill the task). If that's the case, you will need something more sophisticated, such as [this package](https://github.com/LesFerch/TimeRemaining) and be logged in as a standard user while running it.

The script below works best if you have at least two monitors, so that your movie, stream, whatever can be on one screen and DozeGuard can be on another.

**DozeGuard.hta**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>DozeGuard</title>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9">
<hta:application
  icon=perfmon.exe
  scroll=no
  contextmenu=no
  showintaskbar=yes
  singleinstance=yes
  SysMenu=yes
>
<script language="VBScript">
Const DefaultWait = 15 'minutes
Set oWSH = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
Dim TimeLeftInSeconds,WaitTimer
logoutcmd = "Shutdown.exe -l -f"
Scale = GetScale()
w = 300 * Scale: h = 150 * Scale
Window.ResizeTo w, h
Window.MoveTo (screen.availWidth - w)/2, (screen.availHeight - h)/2
TimeLeftInSeconds = DefaultWait * 60

Sub window_onLoad
  UpdateCountdown
  WaitTimer = Window.SetInterval("UpdateCountdown()", 1000)
End Sub

Sub UpdateCountdown
  If Not Paused Then
    Hours = CInt(TimeLeftInSeconds \ 3600)
    Minutes = CInt((TimeLeftInSeconds Mod 3600) \ 60)
    Seconds = TimeLeftInSeconds Mod 60
    CountDown.innerHTML = Hours & ":" & Right("0" & Minutes,2) & ":" & Right("0" & Seconds,2)
    If TimeLeftInSeconds<0 Then
      oWSH.Run logoutcmd,1,False
      self.Close
      Exit Sub
    End If
    TimeLeftInSeconds = TimeLeftInSeconds - 1
  End If
End Sub

Sub ResetCountDown
  TimeLeftInSeconds = DefaultWait * 60
End Sub

Function GetScale()
  GetScale = 1.0
  On Error Resume Next
  'If user changes scale, they must logout/login for this registry value to change
  GetScale = oWSH.RegRead("HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop\WindowMetrics\AppliedDPI") / 96
  On Error Goto 0
End Function

</script>
<style>
body {background-color:black; font-family:Segoe UI; font-size:11pt}
h1 {color:red}
.timerDiv {text-align:center}
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class=timerDiv>
    <h1 id=CountDown></h1>
    <input type=button value='Reset Countdown' OnClick=ResetCountDown()>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```